# Linq - How to apply a where clause on the maximum element of a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-nhibernate

- I have a list of "Person"
- Each Person has a list of "Category"
- Categoty has two atributes: Date and Value

I want to select a list of Person, where the last category equals "B". But I don't know how to write the "where clause" in Linq syntax.

My "person" structure is:

```
<person>
    <id>200</id>
    <name>Peter</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <date>2012-05-01<date>
            <value>A</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-01-01<date>
            <value>B</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-02-01<date>
            <value>C</value>
        </category>
    </categories>
</person>
```

Comment: Is this linq to xml, or linq to nhibernate?

Comment: Hibernate. The XML is just to show the fields of the Person entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are to assume that categories can be out of order by date:

```
var bPersons = persons.Where(p => 
                             p.Categories
                              .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
                              .First().Value == "B")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
List<Person> allPersons = GetListOfPersons();

List<Person> selectedPersons = allPersons
    .Where((x) => x.Categories
                   .OrderBy(y => y.Date)
                   .Last()
                   .Value == "B")
    .ToList();
```

or the query style

```
List<Person> selectedPersons = (from person in allPersons
                                where person.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Last().Value == "B"
                                select person).ToList();
```

Comment: How to set "Date" field to do .Last()

Comment: `Date` and `Value` are interchangeable. You will notice that `Last()` returns the last `Category` in the list of `person.Categories`. So you can use whatever property you want from that object.

Comment: Sorry, "last category" is the category with the latest date. Sometimes it may not be the last inserted

Comment: In that case you would have to order by the date in your where clause. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using XML, you can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var persons = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var seq2 = from person in persons.Descendants("person")
                       where (string) person.Descendants("value").Last() == "B"
                       select person;

            print(seq2);
        }

        private static void print<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq)
        {
            foreach (var item in seq)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
        }

        static string xml =
@"<persons>
<person>
    <id>200</id>
    <name>Peter</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <date>2012-05-01</date>
            <value>B</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-01-01</date>
            <value>A</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-02-01</date>
            <value>C</value>
        </category>
    </categories>
</person>
<person>
    <id>201</id>
    <name>Mary</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <date>2012-05-01</date>
            <value>A</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-01-01</date>
            <value>B</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-02-01</date>
            <value>C</value>
        </category>
    </categories>
</person>
<person>
    <id>202</id>
    <name>Midge</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <date>2012-05-01</date>
            <value>C</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-01-01</date>
            <value>A</value>
        </category>
        <category>
            <date>2013-02-01</date>
            <value>B</value>
        </category>
    </categories>
</person>
</persons>
";

    }
}
```

This prints:

```
-------------------------------------------------
<person>
  <id>202</id>
  <name>Midge</name>
  <age>25</age>
  <categories>
    <category>
      <date>2012-05-01</date>
      <value>C</value>
    </category>
    <category>
      <date>2013-01-01</date>
      <value>A</value>
    </category>
    <category>
      <date>2013-02-01</date>
      <value>B</value>
    </category>
  </categories>
</person>
-------------------------------------------------
```